# Understanding the behaviour of `continue-update-rollback` command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Want to understand the behavior of the `continue-update-rollback` command when the stack has never been created successfully?
In the below scenario, which state would the stack go back to if we initiate `continue-update-rollback`? Will it go to (0), (1), (2), or uncertain?

(0) ----> Stack Creation ---> UPDATE_FAILED (1) -----> UPDATE_FAILED (2) ---> ChangeSet Executed (3) ----> UPDATE_FAILED/UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED (4)---> `continue-update-rollback`  --->  (?)

[Termination Protection was enabled and DisableRollback was enabled when the stack was created]

UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED error is due to some manual changes on the resources outside of cloud formation.

Comment: Is it still unclear how it works?

Answer (score 0):

`continue-update-rollback` command, as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/continue-update-rollback.html), will try to make stack to go

> back to the **UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE** state

Off course this is not guaranteed, a sometimes **manual** intervention is required as described in:

- [How can I get my CloudFormation stack to update if it's stuck in the UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-update-rollback-failed/)